# Using SignalR and SqlDependency with Asp.Net Core 8.0 N-Tier Architecture

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, signalr, n-tier-architecture, sqldependency

I am developing an Asp.Net Core 8.0 API project.

There are 5 layers in my project,

- EntityLayer (Class Library)
- DataAccessLayer(Class Library)
- Business Layer (Class Library)
- DtosLayer(Class Library)
- ApiLayer (Core 8.0 API)
- UI Layer (Core 8.0 MVC)

I want to receive data simultaneously using SignalR and SqlDependency in my project.

In my project, I want to keep interfaces and repositories in the DataAccessLayer layer.
My Hub class must be in the Api layer.
And in the MVC layer, I need to consume the API and display the values in the view.

I have seen many examples of this, but I could not adapt it to N-Tier Architecture. Everyone who explained it only performed the operations in the UI part.

An example link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1159844/implementing-signalr-in-asp-net-core-web-app-(mvc)

My first question is, can I use it with entity framework or dapper ORM?

Secondly, how can I use it in N-Tier Architecture?

Thank for your support.
Thanks.

Comment: Why your  Hub class must be in the Api layer.do you want to consume it in api project?

Comment: In fact, it may be so, after all, it is not against architecture.